# How can I redirect to other page once download is complete?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, redirect

Following is my code to convert HTML into PDF,  what I am trying to implement is as soon as pdf is downloaded I want the page to be redirected to another page: SendEmail.aspx through which I will email the downloaded pdf, Is there any way to do that ?

I tried using Response.Redirect("SendEmail.aspx"); and also removing Response.End but any one of them is working, either it redirects or it downloads pdf, Is there a way I can do both??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

using System.Data;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.Text;

namespace HTMLtoPDF
{
public partial class HTMLtoPDF : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DownloadAsPDF();
    }

    public void DownloadAsPDF()
    {
        try
        {
            string strHtml = string.Empty;
            string pdfFileName = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\files\\" + "CASEID2.pdf";
            //string testPath = Server.MapPath("~/files/test.pdf");

            string template = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Incomplete-Pdf-temp.html"));



            string case_id = "12345";
            string student_id = "";
            string student_name_input = "";
            string campus_input = "Falls Church";
            string email_input = "xyz@gmail.com";
            string phone_input = "";
            string term = "2";
            string address_input = "";
            string course_input = "Mobile Application Development";
            string reason_appeal = "Family Problems";
            string faculty_name = "XYZ";
            string remaining_work = "Task-1,Task-2,Task-3";
            string deadline_date = "May 1st";

            template = template.Replace("[CASEID]", case_id);
            template = template.Replace("[STUDENTID]", student_id);
            template = template.Replace("[STUDENTNAME]", student_name_input);
            template = template.Replace("[CAMPUS]", campus_input);
            template = template.Replace("[EMAIL]", email_input);
            template = template.Replace("[PHONE]", phone_input);
            template = template.Replace("[TERM]", term);
            template = template.Replace("[ADDRESS]", address_input);
            template = template.Replace("[COURSEID] [COURSENAME]", course_input);
            template = template.Replace("[REASON]", reason_appeal);
            template = template.Replace("[FACULTYNAME]", faculty_name);
            template = template.Replace("[REMAININGCOURSEWORK]", remaining_work);
            template = template.Replace("[DEADLINE]",deadline_date);



          //template.Replace("[DEADLINE]", Request[deadline_date]);



            //StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            //HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); 
            //dvHtml.RenderControl(hw);
            //StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

            //strHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
            //sr.Close();

            //string temp2 = template.Replace("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n    <title></title>\r\n\t<meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n", "");



            CreatePDFFromHTMLFile(template, pdfFileName);

            Response.ContentType = "application/x-download";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", "CASEID2.pdf"));
            Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "2;URL=SendEmail.aspx");
            Response.WriteFile(pdfFileName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }



    public void CreatePDFFromHTMLFile(string HtmlStream, string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            object TargetFile = FileName;

            string ModifiedFileName = string.Empty;
            string FinalFileName = string.Empty;




            GeneratePDF.HtmlToPdfBuilder builder = new GeneratePDF.HtmlToPdfBuilder(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
            GeneratePDF.HtmlPdfPage first = builder.AddPage();
            first.AppendHtml(HtmlStream);
            byte[] file = builder.RenderPdf();
            File.WriteAllBytes(TargetFile.ToString(), file);

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(TargetFile.ToString());
            ModifiedFileName = TargetFile.ToString();
            ModifiedFileName = ModifiedFileName.Insert(ModifiedFileName.Length - 4, "1");

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, new FileStream(ModifiedFileName, FileMode.Append), iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS, "", "", iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AllowPrinting);
            reader.Close();
            if (File.Exists(TargetFile.ToString()))
                File.Delete(TargetFile.ToString());
            FinalFileName = ModifiedFileName.Remove(ModifiedFileName.Length - 5, 1);
            File.Copy(ModifiedFileName, FinalFileName);
            if (File.Exists(ModifiedFileName))
                File.Delete(ModifiedFileName);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not from server-side code.  A response is either one thing or it's another, and any given request has exactly one response.  You could perhaps make an AJAX request from client-side code to get the file (not sure what you'd do with the response, but I suspect there are a variety of Stack Overflow questions on that) and then redirect client-side following the completion of the AJAX response.  Though it's not really clear to me why you're doing both of these things.  Is the user then expected to manually upload the file on the next page?  To the server they just got it from?

Comment: Side Note: Your last method's `catch` block (with nothing but `throw ex;` in it) is not only unnecessary, but actually counter-productive because it throws away valuable information about the exception.  You should just remove it entirely.

Comment: @David I want to do both because pdf is send to multiple user as an email and also because it is one kind of agreement so if it is in email it can be verified and can be kept as a record, and last but not least that is the requirement and i can't help it.
Thank You for pointing that catch thing out, i overlooked it because code was working fine and didn't gave warnings too.

Comment: I don't see what all this email business has to do with what David just asked you about how the web application logic should flow.

Comment: OnClick a pdf will be downloaded, after its done i want that page to be redirected to sendemail.aspx page which sends email to muliple user.